# Rails does not load gems from vendor/gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have strange old buggy project on Rails 2.
It have gem's dependencies in config/environment.rb like

```
config.gem "andand"
config.gem "json"
config.gem "chronic"
config.gem "mini_fb"
```

all those gems are located in vendor/gems/

```
andand-1.3.3/
chronic-0.6.7/
json-1.7.3/
mini_fb-1.1.7/
rbet-1.0.3/
redis-3.0.1/
responsys_client-0.0.1/
```

but when i start unicorn server with this app it always complain that it can't find this gems. Why?

**UPDATE**

After building and installing gem from vendor/gems rails still complain about it.

I have tweake mini_fb gem into custom mini_fb_custom gem. Changed all references in gemspec and other files from mini_fb to mini_fb_my, installed it and it is shown in `gem list` as mini_fb_my. But it fails to load from config/environment.rb and complains that

```
Missing these required gems:
  mini_fb_my  >= 0
```

maybe i should rename lib/mini_fb.rb to lib/mini_fb_my.rb
i'll check it.

**UPDATE 2**
Yes, renaming files rocks!

Comment: Have you installed the gems from those directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to install them from those folders, or unicorn will not know where to look for them.

Just install the gems from that directory and unicorn should pick them up.

**UPDATE**

You can install your gems locally with this command

```
gem install --local vendor/gems/gem/gem-name.gem
```

On more recent versions of rails you just specify path on the Gemfile

```
gem "gem-name", path: "path/to/gem"
```

Comment: can you guide me how to do this? something like `rake gems:install` ?
there are some custom plugins which are not in global gems repository, would they install ?

Comment: hm does not seem to install anything

Comment: your update works but it does not helps. I updated original question.

Comment: please that is a completely different question, so make a new one... I believe that the gem name and require are different now that you've customized it... paste me the new question and I will try and answer it. Please mark the answer as correct, since the question shouldn't change and it did solve what it originally asked

Answer (score 0):

My advice: replace the obsolete `gem` configuration with [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) (it works fine with rails 2, there should be a tutorial for rails 2 available on their website).

Configuration through `gem` command, freezing gems, etc. is just pain in the a** and it seemed kinda buggy to me when I'd used it (long time ago).